# Installing VC++ re distributable kit from MSI

Tags: windows-installer

Along with deployment of couple of files (which are put together in the .MSI cabinet itself) MSI needs to spawn a custom exe which is developed in Visual C++. This custom executable spawning requirement is achieved by implementing a custom script in the MSI installer. Even though the MSI's custom script is successfully spawning the custom executable, OS is failing to run that exe due to lack of necessary system libraries on the target system. Installing VC++ Redistributable Kit is deploying necessary system libraries on the target system and hence this kit should be available as an installed application in the target system so that the custom exe executes properly. 
Since this VC++ Redist kit is the prerequisite for this custom executable we are thinking to install this VC++ Redist Kit from the MSI installer itself before spawning the custom exe. We succeeded in spawning the VC++ Redist Kit through the same custom script which was used for spawning the custom executable. After completion of the MSI execution, we could able to see this VC++ Redist Kit in the Add/Remove Programs list. But the issue is even though this kit is installed the Custom executable is NOT recognizing the existence of the Kit and hence the custom executable is still failing to run. 
Can you please guide us towards installing an application during the MSI deployment and making the installed application *active* immediately (without waiting for till the completion of the MSI execution) after its completion such that other sub-processes of the MSI installer recognizes the application existence?

Comment: Next to impossible to diagnose this mishap from the question.  Always favor building these kind of helper exe programs with /MT so you don't care.

Answer (score 0):

To install redistributables with an MSI it is recommended to [use merge modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This is much more stable then a custom action, as you did.

To have the application freshly installed recognize the redistributable make sure you launch it at the end, or very close, of the installation process, using a deferred custom action, so the DLLs registered by the merge module in the system are available.

There is no way (recommended) to make the redistributables available on the machine earlier, from an MSI package. You could install them as prerequisites, before your main MSI is launched, using a bootstrapper, but this would mean you have an EXE as output package, that bundles the prerequisites and your main MSI package.

Comment: I tried by launching the custom action at the end. But things did not work. Am using MakeMSI for building the installer.

Comment: Did you set the custom action be executed deferred?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368268(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yeah, I made the action as deferred.

Comment: When I removed the custom action, MSI succeeded and the files are updated at Windows\WinSXS. But, when I include the custom script, the exe could not recognize the DLL's and hence failing. Due to which all the changes are rolled back by MSI.